# jQuery check the array in .each() item then do something for each item independently

Tags: jquery

I am having a problem understanding how .each() can help me in this scenario. I have a list of speakers in a carousel. Each speaker has different roles. The roles are being outputted by my CMS. I want to check the outputted roles of each speaker, run an if statement and then print an appropriate badge for each speaker depending on their role.

This is how my HTML looks like:

```
<ul class="slider-carousel">
    <li class="speaker-item">
        <h3>Speaker name</h3>
        <div class="speaker-badge"></div>
        <div class="speaker-role">
            <ul class="role">               
                <li>Panelist</li>
                <li>Committee Member</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="speaker-item">
        <h3>Speaker name</h3>
        <div class="speaker-badge"></div>
        <div class="speaker-role">
            <ul class="role">
                <li>Co-Chair</li>
                <li>Committee Member</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="speaker-item">
        <h3>Speaker name</h3>
        <div class="speaker-badge"></div>
        <div class="speaker-role">
            <ul class="role">
                <li>Committee Member</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="speaker-item">
        <h3>Speaker name</h3>
        <div class="speaker-badge"></div>
        <div class="speaker-role">
            <ul class="role">
                <li>Speaker</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>   
</ul>
```

when I try to check each item with this code, it prints Committee Badge for all items even if the speaker does not have the Committee role in the HTML code:

```
$('.slider-carousel li').each( function() { 
    $('.speaker-role .role li').each(function(){
        var speakerRole =  $(this).text();
            if (speakerRole.indexOf('Committee Member')) {
                $('.speaker-badge').text('Committee Badge')
            }
    }); 
});
```

Comment: Is this a Bootstrap thing or generic HTML?

Comment: Bootstrap is also included in the project this is more like a generic/custom HTML

Comment: You are setting `$('.speaker-badge').text()` to "Committee Badge" which applies to all element of the class `.speaker-badge`

Comment: Correct. My question is how to apply this 'Committee Badge' only on speakers who has this role?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `this` to refer to the element being looped over in your each call. So change:

```
$('.speaker-badge').text('Committee Badge')
```

to

```
$(this).closest('.speaker-role').prev('.speaker-badge').text('Committee Badge')
```

This will traverse the DOM relative to your list items, going up via `.closest()`, then to the previous sibling via `.prev()`

Additionally you need to change your `if` to `if (speakerRole.indexOf('Committee Member')>-1)`> when it finds a match it will equal `0` which means it found a match but will evaluate to false.

```js
$('.slider-carousel li').each(function() {
  $('.speaker-role .role li').each(function() {
    var speakerRole = $(this).text();
    if (speakerRole.indexOf('Committee Member') > -1) {
      $(this).closest('.speaker-role').prev('.speaker-badge').text('Committee Badge')
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="slider-carousel">
  <li class="speaker-item">
    <h3>Speaker name</h3>
    <div class="speaker-badge"></div>
    <div class="speaker-role">
      <ul class="role">
        <li>Panelist</li>
        <li>Committee Member</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="speaker-item">
    <h3>Speaker name</h3>
    <div class="speaker-badge"></div>
    <div class="speaker-role">
      <ul class="role">
        <li>Co-Chair</li>
        <li>Committee Member</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="speaker-item">
    <h3>Speaker name</h3>
    <div class="speaker-badge"></div>
    <div class="speaker-role">
      <ul class="role">
        <li>Committee Member</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="speaker-item">
    <h3>Speaker name</h3>
    <div class="speaker-badge"></div>
    <div class="speaker-role">
      <ul class="role">
        <li>Speaker</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: the result is the same, 'Committee Badge' is being printed on all items, even if they don't have that role

Comment: @Marz Forgot to also add to chand your if to `if (speakerRole.indexOf('Committee Member')>-1)`. Updated answer

Comment: it works!! :) now I think I can do the same and run multiple else if statements to show different badges based on the roles.  Do you mind explaining what does >-1 do in this code?

Comment: @Marz As the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) state, "The indexOf() method returns the first index at which a given element can be found in the array, or -1 if it is not present." So your check finds a match in position zero and returns the zero to your if statement. But JavaScript considers zero false in an if statement, so we explicitly check to see that the returned value is greater than `-1` (which is indexOf's way of saying it didn't find a match). So in your case, zero is good (match) but left alone in the if it's bad.

Comment: Very thorough explanation. Thank you!! :)